# Is there a PHP framework w/ ORM (Laravel, Cake, Code Igniter) where we can override the data interaction to get the data from and to a rest api?

Tags: php, rest, cakephp, orm, laravel

What I mean is that I already have a RESTful api to get my data, but I would like to be able to use ORM-like functions to interact with the data.

```
$myobj = new Object();
$myobj->name = "This is my object name";
$myobj->save();
```

As shown over here, the save function is used on the object to save the object directly in the database. But I would like to save the object on a restful api, so the abstraction level or the part I would need to create and separate would be to override the ORM to interact with an API instead of with a database.

I know that's a weird question and I'm pretty sure other people already wanted to do that before me (I can't be alone! ahah) but I didn't find anything online...

Comment: I hate when people down vote without saying why! Cowards! If you down vote, give the OP the reason so they can fix stuff. Your opinion is no better if you do not explain yourself. Put up or shut-up down voters!

Comment: Thanks... I know, it's frustrating since I'm just trying to learn new things and nobody should feel better than anyone else because they think my question is basic. Maybe my question was basic for some people but I'm just trying to figure things out.

Comment: Exactly! And that is what this site is for. But to have some joker just come by and down vote without explanation is irritating. It could just be some troll only with the specific intent to be negative. Sorry for the rant.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I think you might be looking for Datasources if you are asking about the CakePHP framework: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/datasources.html

Once you connect the datasource to your RESTful API, you can then call the data from within the CakePHP application using the ORM syntax.

This is useful for accessing data from other sources too like twitter for example.

Comment: Great! So you basically create your own abstraction level with a class that extends DataSource then you can use your CRUD. Do you still have to define your CRUD functions or does DataSource have default ones to handle restful interactions?

Comment: You can define how the datasource implements CRUD. But then you load the "Model" and call the CRUD methods that same way you would as if you were accessing the database. The abstraction is beautiful!

Comment: That just means I can start with a database and easily port to an api somewhen and vice versa without breaking anything but the datasource files themselves... amazing! Thanks for the help!